# How to trigger apt-action if program is updated/upgraded?

Tags: apt

Question:

I want to do some things if a few special programs are updated/upgraded, that is to say when their executable and/or config files get changed/overwritten.

Specifically, I want to AUTOMATICALLY execute

```
sed -i 's/geteuid/getppid/g' `which vlc`
```

each time vlc has been updated/upgraded

and I want to replace

```
exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome"  "$@"
```

with

```
exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome"  "$@" --user-data-dir=/root/.config/google-chrome
```

in `/usr/bin/google-chrome` each time google-chrome is updated/upgraded.